# Whats the different between videojs() and bc()?

Tags: video.js

I'm implementing videos into my website which are hosted on brightcove. On some examples of initializing the video I see `videojs(document.getElementById('my-video'))` and on others I see `bc(document.getElementById('my-video'))`.

I see on [brightcove's documentations](https://support.brightcove.com/brightcove-player-sample-loading-player-dynamically) they mention `bc()` vs `videojs()` but I don't understand what they are saying.

Can anyone help me understand what the difference is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Brightcove Player is an extension of Video.js. Use `bc(id)` to initialise a Brightcove Player. Using `videojs(id)` to initialise would result in missing some Brightcove-specific customisations which are needed to work with Brightcove Video Cloud.

The confusion arises because `videojs(id)` can also be used as a getter to get an already initialised player, but you want to make sure you don't call that before the Brightcove Player is initialised. Using `videojs.getPlayer(id)` is safer, as it won't initialise an uninitialised player. This was added in Video.js 6.7.0 / Brightcove Player 6.16.0.

- use `bc(id)` to initialise a Brightcove Player
- use `videojs(id)` to initialise regular Video.js
- use `videojs.getPlayer(id)` to get an initialised player

Comment: THANKYOU! You don't know how hard it was to find this seemingly basic information...